# Cannot find module with Jest

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs

I have this class that I want to test with Jest in a nodeJS project

```
import moment from 'moment-timezone';

export class DateUtil {       

    static toTimeZone(date: Date, tz: string): string {
        return moment(date).tz(tz).format();
    }    
}
```

I've created this test:

```
import { DateUtil } from '../../src/util/date.util';


describe('DateUtil', () => {
..
```

but when I run the test I got this error:

```
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module 'moment-timezone' from 'date.util.ts'

      1 | import { Constants } from './constants';
    > 2 | import moment from 'moment-timezone';
        | ^
      3 | 
      4 | 
      5 | export class DateUtil {
```

I have tried to use import in the test class

```
import moment from 'moment-timezone';
```

but then i have this problem

```
TS1259: Module '"C:/Users/sandro/IdeaProjects/bendiciones/node_modules/@types/moment-timezone/index"' can only be default-imported using the 'esModuleInterop' flag
```

and this is my `tsconfig.json` file where  esModuleInterop is set to true

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "lib": [
            "es6",
            "esnext"
        ],
        "declaration": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "lib",
        "rootDir": "src",
        "removeComments": true,
        "strict": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true
    },
    "exclude": [
        "test"
    ]
}
```

I also tried with this  `tsconfig.json` and with the same result

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "lib": [
            "es6",
            "esnext"
        ],
        "declaration": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "lib",
        "rootDir": "src",
        "removeComments": true,
        "strict": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true
    }
}
```

and this is how jtest is configured inside package.json

```
  "jest": {
        "transform": {
            "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest"
        },
        "testEnvironment": "node",
        "testRegex": "/test/.*\\.(test|it)\\.ts",
        "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
            "/coverage",
            "/lib"
        ],
        "moduleFileExtensions": [
            "ts",
            "tsx",
            "js",
            "jsx",
            "json",
            "node"
        ],
        "coverageThreshold": {
            "global": {
                "branches": 80,
                "functions": 80,
                "lines": 80,
                "statements": -20
            }
        },
        "collectCoverageFrom": [
            "src/**/*.ts",
            "!src/index.ts"
        ],
        "coverageReporters": [
            "json-summary",
            "text",
            "lcov"
        ]
    },
```

Comment: The error says what's wrong, you need esModuleInterop enabled in order to use CommonJS and ES modules together. The problem is in how you configured Jest and TS setup, which wasn't shown.

Comment: did you try to include `moment-timezone` by its relative path? `import moment from './node_modules/moment-timezone';`

Comment: same result, the import fails on the test class, not on the other one